# Dynamic page thumbnails

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, thumbnails

I need a way to automatically generate a thumbnail of the target page when the user hover over a URL (hyperlink) on my page.

I've found several examples of people using pre-created .gifs (or other images) to show a thumbnail of the target site while hovering over the link (see example #1), but I need a way to do this dynamically. Is there a way to generate a thumbnail of a page, either on runtime, or an easy way to update the current thumbnail after editing a page?

Simply put; I need to show a thumbnail of the target page when hovering a hyperlink on my page. This thumbnail should not be based on an image that I have to generate myself after each edit, but rather a snapshot of the current page. Much like google does when searching for websites.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Example #1:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-popup-image-viewer/
Hover your mouse over "Zoka Coffee"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to study about this library [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: Will this build the PHP page properly? I understand that an HTML (static) page would be fairly simple to capture, but since this is php it has to load from databases and build the site before it can be viewed properly, to capture a more or less accurate screenshot. Any ideas?

Comment: From user point of view, every page (except JS-based) is simple HTML - it is generated on server and is sent to browser